# Microsoft Teams, Graph API, send message to channel InsufficientPrivileges MessageWritesBlocked-Thread is not marked for import

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, elixir, microsoft-teams

I'm attempting to send a message to a Teams channel programmatically. Nothing special or fancy going on.

The payload (JSON encoded):

```
    %{
      "createdDateTime" => DateTime.utc_now(),
      "from" => %{
        "user" => %{
          "id" => @user_id,
          "displayName" => @display_name,
          "userIdentityType" => "aadUser"
        }
      },
      "body" => %{
        "content" => message
      }
    }
```

My request URL:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/<team_id>/channels/<channel_id>/messages
```

Headers have the authorization bearer token and the Content-Type set to application/json

As far as I know (I don't have direct access to the environment), we have the api permission set to delegate permissions, not application permissions. The role has the ChannelMessage.Send permission. I receive this response:

```
  error: %{
    code: "Forbidden",
    message: "InsufficientPrivileges",
    innerError: %{
      code: "1",
      message: "MessageWritesBlocked-Thread is not marked for import",
      date: "2024-03-27T16:55:18",
      "request-id": "947c97a0-2bdb-4168-b18e-bdebf8de6c86",
      "client-request-id": "947c97a0-2bdb-4168-b18e-bdebf8de6c86"
    }
  }
```

The roles sent back in the access token are the following:

```
"roles": [
    "Chat.UpdatePolicyViolation.All",
    "Teamwork.Migrate.All",
    "Directory.ReadWrite.All",
    "Team.Create",
    "Group.ReadWrite.All",
    "Chat.ReadWrite.WhereInstalled",
    "Chat.Read.WhereInstalled",
    "Chat.Read.All",
    "Chat.ReadBasic.WhereInstalled",
    "Chat.ReadWrite.All",
    "Chat.ReadBasic.All",
    "Chat.ManageDeletion.All",
    "Chat.Create"
  ]
```

Any assistance with this error, as to what permissions/roles I may be missing or other help would be appreciated as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check API permissions and ensure that the Microsoft Graph API permission **ChannelMessage.Send** is correctly set up. For sending messages to a Teams channel, delegated permissions are required, but you might also need **ChannelMessage.Send** specifically for this task.

Comment: Yup, this definitely looks to be the case. OP, you can see more here, where it clearly lists the permission: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http - always check these Graph docs to be sure what you need